# How can I add click events to an array of buttons with their position?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, button

I'm trying to add an event that changes the text of a button when I click on it. However it doesn't matter which one I click, it always changes the text of the last button.

At first I tried by passing the button to the method "pulsar", and always the last button was the one changing. I thought it may be the reference of the variable so I tried passing the possition, but the same happens.

```
class Buscaminas{
    constructor () {
        this.botones = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                let boton = document.getElementById(i + "" + j);
                boton.textContent = "Hi";
                boton.onclick = e => {
                    this.pulsar(6*i+j);
                }
                this.botones.push(boton);
            }
        }
    }

    pulsar = (n) => {
        console.log(n);
        this.botones[n].textContent = "Bye";
    }
}
```

The console.log always prints 55

Comment: Change `var i`, and `var j` to `let i` and `let j`, so the values in each function would be the ones they were declared in, and not the last values.

Comment: Thank you! I thought that as they were numbers it wasn't necesary

Comment: how to show the buttons?

Answer (score 1):

You're approaching this incorrectly.

You never want to add a bunch of individual event handlers to each element in a case where you have lots of elements. You want to create a single event handler at a root node where click events for each child element bubble up to.

In this example, we have 10 divs:

```
<div id="btn-root">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="1">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="2">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="3">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="4">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="5">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="6">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="7">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="8">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="9">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="10">
</div>
```

And we have this simple code that listens for clicks on any of the child ".btn" elements:

```
class Buscaminas {
  constructor() {
    document.querySelector('#btn-root').addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
      evt.target.textContent = Math.random();
    }); 
  }
}

new Buscaminas();
```

If you run that, you'll see that every time you click one of the buttons, its content is replaced with a random number.

Later edit:

Say you're in the case where you want to find the index of the element being clicked. We still don't want to assign individual event handlers for each element, but we aren't provided with the index of the target element in the parent.

To get around this, we want to search through the child nodes of `#btn-root` until it matches. A binary search won't work here, but we want something better than `indexOf` which just does a linear search. What we can do instead is only loop for the length of half the array and check both ends. Then we can get the index fairly efficiently.

```
document.querySelector('#btn-root').addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
  const children = ev.target.parentNode.children;

  for (let i = 0; i < Math.floor(children.length / 2); i++) {
    const lowMatch = ev.target === children[i] && i;
    const highMatch = ev.target === children[children.length - 1 - i] && children.length - 1 - i;
    const index = Number.isInteger(lowMatch) && lowMatch || Number.isInteger(highMatch) && highMatch;

    if (index) {
      ev.target.value = `${index + 1}-${Math.random()}`;
      break;      
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Please note that `div`s styled as buttons are still `div` elements and therefore not accessible for screen readers nor for people who use keyboard navigation.
And while I do understand that you're just providing a simple demo, I think these examples also should have accessibility in mind. At some point someone will use your example to create production code.

Comment: @Arjan yes, but your comment is completely unrelated to the original question. I'm using divs in my answer to illustrate the proper technique for event handling. The same concept is still used for button elements.

Comment: I'm aware that my comment is not directly related to the question, but it is related to your answer. You can show the concept using `<button>` elements (or `<input type="button">`) and at the same time show that buttons should be the first choice for things that require click interaction.

Comment: I had to change the buttons to a 2-dimansional array so this method is a little bit too complicated to get the i and j. Anyway, thank you for your response! I'm still learning and I didn't know I could add eventListeners like that and I'll keep it in mind for the future

Comment: What I don't understand very well are those "$" in `${index + 1}-${Math.random()}`; What do they do?

Comment: @CarmenSirgo They're called template literals. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals. Its a relatively new ES6 feature that allows for easily building strings with variables without needing to do string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```js
function sayHello(e) {
  e.target.textContent = "Darth Vader";
}

var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
buttons.forEach(e => e.addEventListener("click", sayHello, false));
```

```html
<button>Hello</button>
<button>I</button>
<button>Am</button>
<button>Your</button>
<button>Father</button>
```

Comment: Don't do this. You almost never want to add individual event handlers to lots of common elements.

That aside, your code is still incorrect. You'd just need to do `document.querySelectorAll('.btn').map((el) => el.addEventListener('click', () => el.innerHTML = 'whatever'))`

Comment: Why would't you want to add individual event handlers for lots of common elements? I am eager to learn. Why is my code incorrect, it works just fine.

Comment: Think about efficiency. If you have hundreds of elements, it’s more efficient to have a single function than hundreds. By incorrect, I meant that it’s unnecessarily complex. Although I didn’t include it in my example, `map` will return an array of the elements so you could assign it to a variable for future access without needing to do the querySelectorAll again.

Comment: After you posted your comment, I thought a little bit about it, and yes you are are correct. It is unwise to do this. What would you propose as an alternative? Like a global body.document.addEventListener that takes in the event object and does the necessary filtering inside the given function?

Comment: Welp, I'm going through OP's question again because this branches out in a few directions. For just the case of "change the text of an element", my answer below is the most efficient. But what if you need to access the index of the element being clicked? That gets more complicated. To answer your last question, the situation where you want a parent handler varies with what's being done.

Comment: I see... Well if you wanted the index, you could just do this: console.log([...e.target.parentElement.children].indexOf(e.target))

Comment: check the update I just added to my answer below. `indexOf` works, but isn't the most efficient way.

Comment: no need to `[...NodeList]` . NodeList has natively the `NodeList.forEach` method embedded.

Comment: Hey OP, did you find a way to do what you wanted?